# What is the starting point of Hellman's TMTO method?

Tags: hash, diffie-hellman, passwords, password-hashing

I understand what is happening and how the endpoint is computed but I'm still a bit unsure of where "SP" (Staring Point) came from. Are the starting points, randomly selected keys from the key-space n?

for example...

[image: TMTO]

Comment: What reference are you pulling this terminology from? That context would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I've included an example image. Alot of images that I find start with either S or SP for starting point. I'm just trying to figure out exactly what this is.

Answer (score 1):

Given the diagram, yes they are randomly selected keys, $P$ is a fixed plaintext and the projection of the output to the keyspace gives you the next input as key to the cipher, thus creating a pseudorandom walk through the keyspace.